# How to move namespace declaration from inner element to upper element?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, jaxb

I have a java + spring boot app. I'm using jaxws-maven-plugin to generate sources based on .wsdl and .xsd files. I'm sending a soap request receiving response. Unfortunately the response is not 100% the same as expected example that I have from the client.

Expected response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wst13:SecResponse">
         <wst13:SecToken>

            <saml:Assertion ID="A-123"
                    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <saml:AttributeStatement>
                  <saml:Attribute Name="ClientID">
                     <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">hello</saml:AttributeValue>
                  </saml:Attribute>
               </saml:AttributeStatement>
            </saml:Assertion>

         </wst13:RequestedSecurityToken>
      </wst13:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Actual response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wst13:SecResponse">
         <wst13:SecToken>

            <saml:Assertion ID="A-123"
                    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
               <saml:AttributeStatement>
                  <saml:Attribute Name="ClientID">
                     <saml:AttributeValue
                             xsi:type="xsd:string"
                             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">hello</saml:AttributeValue>
                  </saml:Attribute>
               </saml:AttributeStatement>
            </saml:Assertion>

         </wst13:RequestedSecurityToken>
      </wst13:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can see the difference in saml:Assertion element (see at namespaces defined in this element), and saml:AttributeValue element (also see at namespaces defined in this element).

So the question is how can I move the xsi and xsd namecpaces definition from saml:AttributeValue to saml:Assertion element?

What I already tried:

- I created my own namespace mapper (extends NamespacePrefixMapper) to be able to overwrite generated namespace prefixes. Also in this class I was able to move my xmlns:xsi to the root element but I don't want to move it to the root element, but to saml:Assertion element...
- I tried also add marshaller listener, but it looks that it works like above method or I don't know how I can use this listener in a proper way.

Comment: From the XML namespace specification: "The scope of a namespace declaration declaring a prefix extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag". So declaring a namespace prefix for an attribute in the same element context as the attribtue should not be a problem. How is it a problem for you?

Comment: the problem is that some spring or  jaxws-maven-plugin magic is happeing under the hood and when I receive soap response from my service declaration of xsi and xsd namespaces are placed in AttributeValue, but I want them to be placed in saml:Assertion and I don't know where and what should I change...I've just prepared some workaround... I created soap response interceptor, but probably there is better solution for my case, and probably (didn't tested yet) my solution can cause that signed assertion will not be valid because is modified.

Comment: Are you saying that some plugin is changing the XML response? Have you inspected the response before it arrives at you server?